# Create local network share with linux and mac only

Tags: networking, printing, file-sharing

I have several machines within my home that I would like to share files and printer with. All of them are Ubuntu (or a derivative) with the exception of one mac. The mac isn't as important as the rest, so I could take an option that doesn't require it.  A friend said that Samba wouldn't be the best option for security and what not but didn't offer any other options. What is the best options?

Answer (score 0):

For sharing printers best solution, for me, is to user [`cups`](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/cups.html). Also you can user `cups` on mac.

For file sharing you can use `Samba`. You have lot of a resource [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/116309/use-ubuntus-public-folder-to-easily-share-files-between-computers/), and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!), or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide)

Maybe you can use [`NFS`](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html). With `nfs` your network share will be mount on boot.
Example of configuration can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo), and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto).

Or, for file sharing, you can use this [manual](http://www.howtogeek.com/116309/use-ubuntus-public-folder-to-easily-share-files-between-computers/).